# Drawing Spheres, Cylinders, etc. with GLSL 3.0+

Tags: objective-c, macos, opengl, 3d, glsl

Are any tutorials for explaining how to draw a cylinder or sphere using the OpenGL Shading Language?

Comment: GLSL does not (generally) define geometry.

Comment: My understanding is that one cannot use the old stuff like gluCylinder() to draw a cylinder in GLSL. So, hence my question...

Comment: That you can not use gluCylinder with GLSL is not due to a lack of GLSL, but because GLU drawing functions use completely outdated OpenGL API. If the GLU functions did use well known vertex attributes and use modern OpenGL drawing APIs you could apply GLSL just fine to them.

Answer (score 2):

> Are any tutorials for explaining how to draw a cylinder or sphere using the OpenGL Shading Language?

No, because that's not what GLSL does (well, actually using geometry shaders and tesselation shaders it could be done, but that's not what GLSL is for).